# Fantasy trilogy with 'winged steeds' ridden by 'guardians'

Tags: story-identification, novel

I believe it is a trilogy.

There are guardians who ride winged steeds. There are a number for the world.
These guardians have portals on the top of very high places that can only be reached by the winged steeds.

Some of the guardians have been subverted to evil.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read these books, and when do you think they might've been published?

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Answer (score 5):

Could this be the [*Crossroads*](https://www.goodreads.com/series/44731-crossroads) series of books by Kate Elliott? Not actually a trilogy, although there are only three books in the series thus far.

Per the description for the first book, [*Spirit Gate*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/210197.Spirit_Gate)

> For hundreds of years the Guardians have ruled the world of the
> Hundred, but these powerful gods no longer exert their will on the
> world. Only the reeves, who patrol on enormous eagles, still represent
> the Guardians' power. And the reeves are losing their authority; for
> there is a dark shadow across the land that not even the reeves can
> stop.

[image]

Comment: Did you never read [Black Wolves](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/20980680-black-wolves)? Publisher dropped the rest of the books but not the rights, so Elliott's been stuck.